# Sending xAPI statements to an LRS

Tags: xapi, lrs

I'm trying to send xAPI statements from an "Activity Provider" to the ADL LRS live demo. The goal is to implement this from my C# .NET application, but I was having trouble implementing it so I tried running a simple POST request from JMeter.

[image: the request screenshot]

I do get a 200 response, but when I try to check whether the statement was successfully stored at https://lrs.adlnet.gov/me/statements, it's empty.
Am I completely misunderstanding how this structure is supposed to work? I'm going to install the ADL LRS eventually for testing purposes, but I wanted to get the actual request structure worked out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path looks incorrect, the POST should be to `{endpoint}/statements`, so in your case it looks like it should be `https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xAPI/statements`.  Additionally you should make sure you are setting the `X-Experience-API-Version` header. If this doesn't solve the issue, you should look at more than just the response status code, and see what the body contains (and add it to your question). The body for the type of request you are sending should return JSON, with an array with a single statement identifier in it. Additionally when you retrieve the statements the URL you use should match the one that you specify when you send, so `/me/` is not correct.

If it is a basic C# .NET project you may be interested in https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCan.NET. It is showing its age, but in general for a number of projects it will still work or would at least be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'll try your corrections and check back! To clarify, the /me/ is a page on the site that I think is meant to display statements that have been sent, not a URL I'm using for a request.

Comment: Update: I ran into a different issue in JMeter, but TinCan.NET works well so my project is back on track